# STATA - Synchronise two Y-axis

Tags: stata

I would like to create some reference line in my graph. My idea was to place them on a second axis where I could also reference their value and name (though I can't seem to be able to get both on the graph so I left the value).

The problem is that even though using the same range of values for scales (MAX and MIN), the axis do not seem to be aligned.

I understand there may be a better way to do this altogether but firstly I would like to know why it isn't behaving as I would assume it to.

This is a visual of my graph:

[image: Current Graph]

And the code used to visualise it:

```
quietly summarize sent

graph twoway                                                /// 
    (tsline sent)                                           /// 
    (tsline sent, yaxis(2) lcolor(none)),                   /// 
                                                            ///
    title("Requests by Day", size(medsmall))                /// 
                                                            ///
    ttitle("Date", size(small))                             ///
    tlabel(#15, labsize(vsmall) format(%tdd_m))             ///
                                                            ///                     
    ytitle("Requests", size(small) axis(1))                 ///     
    ylabel(#8, axis(1) labsize(vsmall))                     /// 
    yscale(range(`=r(min)', `=r(max)') axis(1))             ///
                                                            ///                             
    ylabel(`=r(min)' `=r(max)' , axis(2) labsize(vsmall))   ///
    ytitle("", axis(2))                                     ///
    yline(`=r(min)', lcolor("blue") axis(2))                ///
    yline(`=r(max)', lcolor("green") axis(2))               ///
    yscale(range(`=r(min)', `=r(max)') axis(2))
```

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, but change the `yscale` for `axis(2)` to mirror `axis(1)`. Namely, `yscale(range(200000, 340000) axis(2))`. That should do the trick. How you have written it, you scale the second `yaxis` to be min/max and then draw a `yline` at those values. You should scale it to match the first axis and then draw a `yline` at the min/max values. Essentially, you need the scales to align for `axis(1)` and `axis(2)`.

Comment: But the scale for `axis(1)` is taken from min/max values of the variable, and I used the same code for both scales? I have change the order of the code moving yscale to the beginning of the section and lines underneath it but that didn't change anything

Comment: Okay I think I know what you meant and what you suggested worked of course but why would the left axis be 200000-340000 if I specifically used a MIN/MAX range? I realised now that it's the left axis that doesn't adhere to the paramters I specified. So is this `yscale(range(`=r(min)', `=r(max)') axis(1))` even allowed?

Comment: It is allowed. I suspect it is ignored or overridden to some extent here because of `ylabel(#8, axis(1) labsize(vsmall))`. That piece forces 8 numbers in to the axis, and those 8 may or may not line up nicely with the data. If they don't, Stata will decide how many to use for you. In this case they do so you get the range 200000 - 340000. I'm not positive that's what is happening, but that is where I'd start looking.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will have a play with those labels and come back with any findings